# verilog behavioral RTL to structural

Tags: counter, verilog

I been assigned to manually convert the below RTL into its structural equivalent.  I don't understand how you'd convert it. What's the structural description for this code in verilog? What steps should I take?

```
module cou(
  output reg [7:0] out,
  input [7:0] in,
  input iti,
  input c,
  input clock);

  always @(posedge clock)
    if (iti == 1)
      out <= in;
    else if (c == 1) 
      out <= out + 1;
endmodule
```

Comment: And how do I do that ?
Do you mean the "View RTL schematic" option ? I need code not that.

Btw, I'm using xilinx ise 14.7.

Comment: What have you tried? This looks like a homework assignment. My old college professor would ask us to manually convert RTL to structural and back. It taught us how to synthesis tool translate RTL and the importance of good coding practices.

Comment: Without a synthesis tool you will need to figure out the behavior of this code and then figure out what structural elements will get you the same behavior.

Comment: I'm a beginner and don't actually understand what I have to do. 
Browsing the internet and reading tutorials on this topic hasn't helped me to understand how I should do such a thing.
Yes, it's a homework assignment.

Comment: I'll get you started: at the positive edge of `clock` the `out` signal gets the value of `in` if `iti` is high, otherwise it gets set to `out+1` if `c` is high. Leaving it up to you to figure out how to make that happen in gates.

Comment: @xqer, please clarify. Are you trying to convert RTL to strctural manually or are you trying to learn how to synthesize with a tool(xilinx ise 14.7)?

Comment: I have to do it manually. So it'll be (I think) something similar to this example for the adder:
    module adder (
         input a,
         input b,
         input cin,
         output s,
         output cout );
         
         wire w1, w2, w3;
    
         and( w1, a, b );
         and( w2, a, cin );
         and( w3, b, cin );
         or( cout, w1, w2, w3 );
        
         xor( s, a, b, cin );

endmodule

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic process:

- `always @(posedge clock)` tells you you have positive-edge D-flip-flops without an asynchronous reset or set.
- `out` is the only value being assigned within the `always` statment. The size of `out` tells you the number of flops needed.
- Drawing a component level schematic diagram can help visualize the structural logic.

Now all that is needed to figure out is the combination logic to the flop's D pin. I'll give you a clue that it can be done using only muxes and an adder.

Comment: Ok. After reading the replies it's beginning to make sense even though I haven't finished, but it's imho way to hard for what we've done until now. 
Is there any good place for a complete novice to learn verilog ?

Comment: @xqer, I would focus on breaking down the problem, I can see 3 stages. Greg has done a good job of explaining the `always @(posedge clk)` which is likely the most confusing part. Consider the `if` statements independently. Think about the `out <= out + 1;` Once you understand those parts start putting it all together.